# How to make a REST delete method with cfhttp

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have never done it before and now when the need arise, things are not working.
I have to send an ID to delete a DB record with RESTful service. Here is the code I am trying:

```
<cfhttp url="http://127.0.0.1:8500/rest/test/something" method="DELETE" port="8500" result="qryRes1">
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="36"/>
</cfhttp>
```

and in the REST function

```
remote any function someName() httpmethod="DELETE"{
var testID = ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content);
//make db call to delete
return testid;
}
```

The result comes as blank [empty string]. I am not able to retrieve the sent value in function. What I am missing?
**Edit:** one slightly different but related to CF rest, is it necessary to convert query to an array before sending it back to client? Directly serializing won't solve the purpose same way?

Comment: That might be an approximation of your rest function, but it doesn't look like the *actual* function you're talking about (it's not remote, it doesn't have all the rest attributes, etc). So can you pls post the *actual* function? We can't really just guess what the issue might be.

Comment: That is all in the function definition (except the changed function/variable names). I was getting error that value is not numeric. So I tried to return it to see and it is empty. I am unable to find out whether is this the way I am sending variable value or way I am reading it.

Comment: you may want to take a look at `deleteUser()` in http://www.anujgakhar.com/2012/02/20/using-rest-services-in-coldfusion-10/ as an example of how to support DELETE in REST API style.

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't look syntactically correct for a ColdFusion 10 REST function declaration. @Henry's put you onto reasonable examples for the syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Henry, I had figured that by try sending as QUERY restargsource and it accepted that. After seeing the link I reckon restargsource has to be either PATH or QUERY. Request body I guess is not read. That link was also helpful for some other things. Can you post your comment as answer. One side question, I am adding that in original question too, is it necessary to convert query to an array before sending it back to client? Directly serializing won't solve the purpose same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to take a look at `deleteUser()` in http://www.anujgakhar.com/2012/02/20/using-rest-services-in-coldfusion-10/ as an example of how to support DELETE in REST API style.

```
remote any function deleteUser(numeric userid restargsource="Path") httpmethod="DELETE" restpath="{userid}"
{
    var response = "";
    var qry = new Query();
    var userQry = "";

    qry.setSQl("delete from tbluser where id = :userid");
    qry.addParam(name="userid", value="#arguments.userid#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric");
    userQry = qry.execute().getPrefix();

    if(userQry.recordcount)
    {
        response = "User Deleted";
    } else {
        throw(type="Restsample.UserNotFoundError", errorCode='404', detail='User not found');
    }

    return response;
}
```

As for the 2nd part of your question, it'd be best to first turn a query into a array of structs first unless you're using CF11 which does it for you.  See: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/5/8/ColdFusion-11s-new-Struct-format-for-JSON-and-how-to-use-it-in-ColdFusion-10

The default JSON structure for query in CF 8 to 10 were designed for `<cfgrid>` in ColdFusion on top of Adobe's discontinued [Spry framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spry_framework).